# I.E. Download Pop Up and Taskbar getting merge

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, internet-explorer-9, taskbar

I have hosted a website running on I.E. When I download something ,explorer's download pop up get merge behind Windows Taskbar,is there any way to prevent this?[May be some javaScript function to handle this or any other possible solution to resolve this]

Comment: @DarkNight let us know what you have done ?